# error passing string argument to fstream.open

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am using MinGW Developer Studio with the MinGW compiler. I have a small program with the following function:

```
void NameFile()
{
ofstream outfile;
string sFilename = "glatisant.html";
outfile.open(sFilename, ofstream::out);
outfile.close();
}
```

When building,/compiling, I get the following error text:

> main.cpp:43: error: no matching function for call to `std::basic_ofstreamstd::char_traits >::open(std::string&, const std::_Ios_Openmode&)'
>
> fstream:695: note: candidates are: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, >_Traits>::open(const char*, std::_Ios_Openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = >std::char_traits]

According to the definition of fstream.out(), I should be able to pass a string and have it work, but it doesn't. Why not?

Note: the error message seems to indicate that my compiler doesn't recognize the possibility of a string-type argument, which is defined in c++ 11. I think I need to get my environment to use c++ 11, because I would really prefer the modern standards-compliant approach.

Answer (score 1):

In non-C++11, method [`ofstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) requires `const char *`, so try to pass `sFilename.c_str()`:

```
outfile.open(sFilename.c_str(), ofstream::out);
                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise in C++11 you can pass a `std::string` too, make sure you have enabled `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x`.

In MingW-Developer-Studio you can goto Projects > Settings > Compile and put `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` in "Extra compiling options"

[image]

Comment: I figured c++ 11 would be default. How do I set it?

Comment: I will research that quickly; I haven't really dealt with makefiles and don't know precisely what "compile command" refers to.

Comment: Goto "Project Settings" then click on tab "Compile", after that put `--std=c++11` in "Extra compiling options".

Comment: I did try that and it doesn't seem to recognize the command.    g++.exe: C:\Users\Admin\Documents\MinGW Studio Projects\PageCreator\Debug\main.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: no input files More importantly: "cc1plus.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11""

Comment: I'm not getting an error message regarding that command line option anymore, but it's giving me the same code error as before. I'm a wee bit confused.

Comment: What's your gcc's version?

Comment: The option is not `--std=c++11`, there should only be a single leading dash: `-std=c++11`.

Comment: @MM. It appears to be gcc 3.4.5

Comment: Having established this, gcc.gnu.org indicates that support for C++ 11 is incomplete and in development in gcc 3.4.5. This could mean that they simply haven't gotten around to modifying outfile.open() to accept strings. That could be it. Perhaps I assumed too much in thinking that the latest standard would be completely implemented in my compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant `ios_base::out` instead of `ofstream::out`.

Also, in `C++98/C++03`, the input to `ofstream::open` is a `char const*`, not a `std::string`.

If you are using `C++98/C++03`, change the line

```
outfile.open(sFilename, ofstream::out);
```

to

```
outfile.open(sFilename.c_str(), ios_base::out);
```

If you are using `C++11`, all is well.

Comment: In C++11, `ofstream::out` works well, so he doesn't have to change it. See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac466093345ec74b)